# Magento 2 Add new column in Customer Page from data from database

Tags: magento2, customer, collection

I would like to ask if there is an effective way to add column in Customer's Page Grid in magento admin. I have viewed all tutorials and same problems in the web but no luck on displaying the data. I would like to display the updated_at column from the database to customer's page grid

Please refer to the attached email.

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`updated_at` field is available in `customer_entity` table and we are using `customer_grid_flat` table to display customer grid data in Magento. So if you want to display `updated_at` field in your grid then you should follow below steps.

Create `customer_listing.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml

Content for this file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="100">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated At</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Create `di.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

Content for this file is...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Collection" type="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\CustomerDataProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">customer_grid_flat</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Now you need to create one `CustomerDataProvider` UI component file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Ui/Component/Listing/CustomerDataProvider.php

Content for this file is...

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing;

class CustomerDataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
   protected function _initSelect()
   {
      parent::_initSelect();
      $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
        ['ce' => $this->getTable('customer_entity')],
        'main_table.entity_id = ce.entity_id',
        ['updated_at']
      );
      return $this;
  }
}
```

That's it. [Download this module here](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-customer-grid-updated-at-field)

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Thanks Buddy! This only works

Answer (score 0):

Here is the module which worked to create a custom column in any admin grid. 
You have to implement same for customer grid:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13l29KVZSekCBEmzNtuxc3FsqjoCI9UL1/view

Comment: This uses left join. At the moment I do not know how to query in magento 2. I need it to be in the same table without joins

Comment: Class DirectSalesIO\Core\Helper\ReferralCode is missing. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Remove that helper line

Comment: Send the query, i will edit it for you and will remove join

Comment: I already removed and was working. But There is an error. Undefined index: updated_at. updated_at is my column in the database. I also got this error when I tried some different approach with regards to this issue

Comment: where you re getting this error? in adminpanel dashboard or while running upgrade command?

Comment: At the admin dashboard. this is the line where is error is $item[$this->getData('name')];

Comment: check table, there must be `updated_at` field. if it exists then run `upgrade` and `di:compile` command

Comment: Hope it will work, if you satisfy with my answer then do vote up and mark my answer as right.

Comment: There is Updated_at at the database. I think there an error because there is no value returned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100968/discussion-between-temper-and-miguel-intoy).

Comment: Sent you a message. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by using this code.

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $updatedat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($item['entity_id']);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $updatedat->getUpdatedAt();
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
```

But when I sort. This error pops out

```
Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.
```

I think I should also add a sort function to this.

Comment: If you'll use my solution then you can see filter also working there. Please try that once. :)

Comment: Sure. Ill update you once done. Thanks

Comment: The error is still there. Nothing Changed

Comment: Did you removed your code ?

Comment: Yes. I followed all of your instructions

Comment: First of all remove your files which you have created for updated_at field and then please create all 3 files which I've added in my answer.

Comment: Ill try that. Update you later

Comment: Let me know, if you're still getting any errors here then.

Comment: The error is still here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101001/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-miguel-intoy).

Comment: Please click on chat link