# Magento 2: Error when clicking custom column on grid

Tags: magento2, customer-grid

I have created a custom column updated_at on customer grid. I have displayed it with data. But when I click the column header, this error pops out (Something went wrong with processing the default view and we have restored the filter to its original state.)

I added customer_listing on adminhtml/ui_components.

This is the code inside my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <column name="updated_at" class="Mvn\Cam\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomerList">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string" translate="true">MMM d, Y hh:mm a</item>
                    <item name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Updated At</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Here is my code at Ui\Component\Listing\Column

```
<?php
namespace Mvn\Cam\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class CustomerList extends Column
{
    protected $customerFactory;
    protected $_searchCriteria;
    protected $helperReferralCode;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, //my custom module from which i want to add new column
        array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $updatedat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')->load($item['entity_id']);
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $updatedat->getUpdatedAt();
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Here is the Screenshot of the page

[image]

Comment: You can follow my answer on this post https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295433/magento-2-add-new-column-in-customer-page-from-data-from-database/295544?noredirect=1#comment425237_295544

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because you are using a renderer class for the column.

An Issue will also appear if you try to filter in the same column.

There are 2 ways

1. Disable sortable and filterable.
2. Use join in the data provider class of your UI component to fetch the column value (I recommend to do this to avoid future consequences).