# Add column to customer_grid_flat from customer_entity.update_at

Tags: magento2, customer

I would like to ask how to create a new column in customer_grid_flat that will be named updated_at and will get the values from customer_entity.update_at. Tried indexer but it does not add any columns in the customer_grid_flat table. Need help! Thanks!

Comment: check this reference : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295433/magento-2-add-new-column-in-customer-page-from-data-from-database/295496#295496

Answer (score 2):

Resolve this by adding the custom column in customer_grid_flat.

added db_schema.xml at module/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="customer_grid_flat" resource="default" engine="innodb">
        <column xsi:type="datetime" name="nickname" nullable="true" length="40" comment="Nickname"/>
    </table>
```

Then added mview xml on same folder for indexer viewid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Mview/etc/mview.xsd">
    <view id="dummy" class="Vendor\Merchandizing\Model\Indexer\Popular" group="indexer">
        <subscriptions>
            <table name="customer_grid_flat" entity_column="entity_id" />
        </subscriptions>
    </view>
</config>
```

indexer xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Indexer/etc/indexer.xsd">
    <indexer id="customer_grid" view_id="dummy" class="Magento\Framework\Indexer\Action\Entity" primary="customer">
        <fieldset name="customer" source="Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\Collection"
                  provider="Magento\Customer\Model\Indexer\AttributeProvider">
            <field name="updated_at" xsi:type="filterable" dataType="datetime"/>
        </fieldset>
    </indexer>
</config>
```

Run command:

```
php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Codes for adding custom column is at:
[Magento 2 Add new column in Customer Page from data from database](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295433/magento-2-add-new-column-in-customer-page-from-data-from-database/295544#295544)

Kishan Savaliya's answer.